# Formula to change entries based on duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Basically I have a table of approximately 56000 records to be used as a source data for a pivot table.

There are duplicate values in the first column as well as unique values. My goal is, if a duplicated event in column A has both a Yes and No in column B, I need to change it all to a Yes for that particular duplicated event. Is there an Excel function to do so?

Comment: So, essentially, if a record has 'No' in column B, and its column A value is duplicated in another record that says 'Yes' in column B, then change this record to say 'Yes'?

Comment: Yes, basically a "Yes" trumps all "No's" for an event that has both yes and no. Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a column between column A and B, this column will be the new column B.

Insert the following formula in cell B2 (I'm assuming that you have column labels in the first row).

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,C:C,"Yes")>0,"Yes","No")
```

Drag/fill to the bottom.

If there is any one value in column A that has a `Yes` in C, it will return `Yes`.

You might want to copy/paste as values and removing column C after that to lighten your worksheet.

Comment: It worked. You are a "lifesaver"! Thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: cool.  blows away my half written method using combinations of if(), isna() and vlookup()

Comment: @user300036 You're welcome :)